# Why router query not update immediately in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

When I trigger a function to update query, the url become to '?test=1' but console log of query is still empty.

```js
methods: {
  test() {
    this.$router.push({ query: { test: 1 } });
    console.log(this.$route.query);
  }
}
```

But I use the same method in Vue. It works fine that console log of query gets {test:'1'}.
If I want to get the correct query in Nuxt immediately, how can I do?
I have knew two ways can work

1. watch
2. setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.$route.query)},0);

But I want to use better solution, any others methods can work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `watch` on `$route.query`:

```js
methods: {
  test() {
    this.$router.push({ query: { test: 1 } });
  },
},
watch: {
  '$route.query'(q) {
    console.log(q);
  },
},
```

Comment: oh, I forget to say. I have tried 2 methods can work
1. watch 
2. settimeout(()=>{console.log(this.$route.query)},0)
But I want to know any others methods. Because I want to use better solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What problem did you have with the watch?  Why are you looking for a different solution?

Comment: I think watch will lose performance, and setTimeout looks ugly code. So I want to know any other methods can work.

Comment: You have a wrong idea about watch, there is no damage to performance.  It simply listens for a change in the dependency.

Comment: I thought watch would occupy memory all the time. Hmm...okay, I think I need to review document.